# Docker in windows 10 pro: python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, windows, docker

I am using docker in windows 10. My docker project was running well but after updating the docker desktop to 19.03.8, i am facing this error for my existing project. Before updating docker desktop, the project was running very well. But I created another django project for testing which is running without any error.
[This is dockerfile of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pt4C.jpg)[This is docker compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFLvq.jpg) [This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntl0x.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Dockerfile, you are just copying requirements.txt from local system and the code isn't copied. You need to add your code which contains `manage.py`.

Hence the error `[manage.py] No such file or directory

Comment: Can you please tell how can I do that?? because I used the same code before that ran without error. I am new in docker so having issues.

Comment: Well I can't comment how it worked before, but from the image it just copies the requirement file.

You can copy all of your source code with this command:

`COPY . /code` where 'code' is the directory which you will need to create. This will essentially copy everything in current directory to 'code'

You can follow the [Docker best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/). hope this helps!